# How to add focus to an anchor that doesn't have an href?

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, accessibility

I have a large site and there are hundreds of anchor tags that don't have `href` attributes attached. Rather than take the risky step of doing a search/replace and adding `href="#"`, I'd prefer to target them using CSS. I'm trying to apply a focus state to those, but it's proving difficult. I'm using the following `:not([href])` to target those non-href links, but I can't seem to get focus on it.

```css
/* Duru Sans */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Duru+Sans&display=swap");
/*resets*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Duru Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60vh;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.custom-bttn-anim:not([href]), a.custom-bttn-anim {
  align-items: center;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 1.062rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 185px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 1.25rem 0;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
a.custom-bttn-anim:not([href]):hover, a.custom-bttn-anim:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
a.custom-bttn-anim:not([href]):before, a.custom-bttn-anim:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 0px #005fec;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  border-radius: 4px;
  filter: blur(4px);
}
a.custom-bttn-anim:not([href]):focus-visible:before, a.custom-bttn-anim:focus-visible:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 2px #005fec;
  top: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0px);
}
a.custom-blue-bttn {
  background: #005fec;
  color: white;
}
a.custom-bttn-anim .bttn-txt {
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(0.625rem);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
a.custom-bttn-anim .learn-more-arrow {
  height: 0.75rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
}
a.custom-bttn-anim:hover .bttn-txt {
  transform: translate(0px);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}
a.custom-bttn-anim:hover .learn-more-arrow {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="custom-bttn-anim custom-blue-bttn light" href="#">
    <span class="bttn-txt">Small business</span>
    <img src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation_white.svg" alt="right arrow icon" class="learn-more-arrow">
  </a>

  <a class="custom-bttn-anim custom-blue-bttn light">
    <span class="bttn-txt">Small business</span>
    <img src="https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation_white.svg" alt="right arrow icon" class="learn-more-arrow">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor elements without an `href` attribute are not focusable by default.

You can make them focusable with the `tabindex` attribute, although I'm not sure that's any better for you than adding `href="#"`.

Example:

```
<a tabindex="0">
    <!-- other stuff -->
</a>
```

You could even use some JavaScript to add the attributes dynamically:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a:not(a[href])").forEach(element => {
    element.setAttribute("tabindex", "0")
});
```

If the empty anchor tags don't navigate to a URI, then this configuration will likely be confusing for people using assistive technology, and a button with an attached event handler might be a more appropriate choice.

Comment: Adding tabindex does focus the element, but doesn't give it the behavior of a link (pressing enter doesn't activate the element), but changing the attribute from `"tabindex", "0"` to `"href", "#"` does work out just fine. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: it sounds like you might be better off using a button, unless these elements are used for navigation.